# Need help with ordination questions

Tags: monk, monasticism, ordination

I'm a westerner, non-thai speaker, age 37. I want to ordain in Asia (not in the West) and then stay there for 5 years with a preceptor and then either continue to stay there or move back to Europe and live as monk but the problem is that not many placese in Europe have monks living. Also where should one ordain in Sri Lanka or Thailand? I read about Ven. Ajahn Chah who made monasteries for westerners to ordain but where should one stay afterwards?

Can one live alone after the 5 years or more and how would a lonely monk survive in Europe?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to look for is the observance of Descipline(sila) and View(ditthi), since they are the first factors in the Threefold-training and Noble-eghtfold-path respectively. They are the most important criteria while seeking a place to ordain.

One can look for other qualities next, such as austerity, meditation  etc.

There are places that supports meditation, ordination and forest-practice with renowned masters, yet many of them either weak in Vinaya or View, as described in the texts.

Investigating beforehand about the View-alignment and Vinaya-alignment of the teacher and monastery is a wise way to make a decision.

There are some links that I could find addressing these issues but there can be more on the internet if one is willing to investigate.

- [Where to Ordain? Vinaya Comparison of Monasteries](https://classicaltheravada.org/t/vinaya-comparison-of-monasteries/261)
- [Where to Ordain? Philosophy Matching](https://americanmonk.org/where-to-ordain/)
- [Hard to find Classical-Vinaya Protecting Monasteries in Thailand](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheravadaBuddhism/comments/wzzlbf/hard_to_find_classicalvinaya_protecting/)

Comment: Thank you very much Blake.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best place whole over the world for you to take maximum out of your time as you wish.  Go to this site and go to contact page. ["Nissarna Wanaya - Rev. Uduiriyagama Dhammajiwa"](https://www.nissarana.lk/)

You may come with full of bags but after completing your period you may go like free bird with empty hand. You let go all carryings with you. Remove ego completely and be happy forever. This is in Sri Lanka.  Also you can find western people practising Vipassana Meditation. May triple Gem Bless you.

Comment: Dear Sanath, again dear friend, thank you so much for your reply. I will check out the link you sent. May you be well and happy and reach Nibbana soon. This place looks wonderful and incredibly wholesome and secluded.

Comment: My Pleasure and you are most welcome. Yes this is very good place for the people searching freedom of life.  Me too recently find this community and I felt I can share my knowledge of dhamma for the sake of other people those who seeking help to find the reality of this illusion.  May you be able to find freedom of your life soon.  May triple Gem Bless you!!!

Comment: Also, If you are coming to Sri lanka let me know I can guide you to the place until you meet Rev. Uduiriyagama Dhammajiwa Theru. Tehre is no problem about your food and logging they all are provided by the people to the temples in Sri Lanka.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindness - I will definitely contact you if I come to SL. I just found this website with many books by Ven. Dhammajiva. I'm downloading them as we speak and have read in several of them. He speaks fluent English, Sinhala and Burmese and has translated for Ven. Pa-Auk Sayadaw and he's highly trained in both Samatha and Burmese Vipassana meditation techniques. What an amazingly accomplished being.

Comment: Here it is: https://www.vipassana.org/meditation/dhammajiva/index.html.

Comment: Yes exactly, that is why I recommend rather than wasting time for different aspects a person who is searching for the ultimate realities the for noble truths as far as I know this is the exact place. I have to emphasise one thing Master can do only 25% by directing you to the correct path rest 75% in our hand.  Everyday they have sessions for clear your questions and occurrences explaining that you faced while you are meditating which is very important.  We Called that "Kamatahan Shuddhiya".  Also,  it helps you to discuss your achievements and further improvements.  this guidance is important

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139264/discussion-between-sanath-and-daydream-castle).

Answer (score 0):

"Can one live alone after the 5 years or more and how would a lonely monk survive in Europe?"

One worry about life and making a living isn't fit to leave dependency.

And leaving home requires to do so, not seeking another, or not willing to abound "western". And certain strange if thinking on returning, or?

Comment: Thank you Bhante.